# Firebase Realtime Database CORS issue with custom token

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on application that use fire-base realtime database. It was working fine before when no authentication method are in place. Now on login i create custom token for user from my server. And i login into fire-base but after 1 hours browser show following error.
Failed to load https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: For how long is your token valid? If it is after an hour every time maybe you should change the expiration time of the token or refresh it.

Comment: I using  Firebase Admin sdk which manage refresh token by itself.

Comment: Issue was resolved as i was running web in development without server. Move your code to server and allow this server to domain under Authored domains.